# Nested "where" or "let in" CodeStyle in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction

I faced with some issue in Haskell: code-style and big functions (I'm continuing to learn Haskell through writing toy-language).

I have some necessary-big-function (see example). And there are two sub-function (nested where) in it. And there is no reason to place its sub-finction in module scoupe.
How "Haskell code-style" or "Haskell code-style best practics" suggest to solve this problem of "ungraceful and clumsy code"?

Function (with later comment):

```
-- We can delete (on DCE) any useless opers.
-- Useful opers - only opers, whitch determine (directly or transitivery) result of GlobalUse oper
addGlobalUsageStop :: [Var] -> IR -> IR
addGlobalUsageStop guses iR = set iOpers (ios ++ ios') $ set opN opn' iR
    where
    ios = _iOpers iR
    gdefs = _gDefs iR :: M.Map Int Var
    opn = _opN iR
    guses' = nub $ filter isRegGlobal guses
    ogs = catMaybes $ map (concatIOperWithGDef gdefs) $ reverse ios
        where
        concatIOperWithGDef gdefs' (i, o) = case gdefs' M.!? i of
            Nothing -> Nothing
            Just gd -> Just (o, gd)
    nops = newGUses ogs guses'
        where
        newGUses [] _ = []
        newGUses _ [] = []
        newGUses ((Oper _ d _ _, g):os) guses = if elem g guses
            then (Oper GlobalUse g (RVar d) None):newGUses os (filter (g /=) guses)
            else newGUses os guses
    ios' = zip [opn..] nops
    opn' = opn + length ios'
```

Notices:

1. If you want to know why I even wrote such big function the answer is:
   because this is some big (and one-needed functionality in compiler): - for each "returning variable" we shoul find last operation, witch defines it (actually corresponding virtual register), and expand our IR with constructed opers.
2. I'v seen some similar questions: [Haskell nested where clause and "let ... in" syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575128/haskell-nested-where-clause-and-let-in-syntax)
   but they are about "how typewrite correct code?", and my question "is this code Code-Style correct, and if it isn't - what should i do?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a good one, but the example code isn't a great example. For me, the correct fix *in this particular case* is not to talk about how to stylishly nest `where`s; it's to talk about how to use library functions and language features to simplify the code enough that you don't need `where` in the first place. In particular, list comprehensions get you very far here. Here's how I would write those two definitions:

```
import Data.Containers.ListUtils (nubOrdOn)

... where
    ogs = [(o, gd) | (i, o) <- reverse ios, Just gd <- [gdefs M.!? i]]
    nops = nubOrdOn fun
        [ Oper GlobalUse g (RVar d) None
        | (Oper _ d _ _, g) <- ogs
        , g `elem` guses'
        ]
    fun (Oper _ g _ _) = g -- this seems useful enough to put at the global scope; it may even already exist there
```

Since `ogs` isn't mentioned anywhere else in the code, you might consider inlining it:

```
    -- delete the definition of ogs
    nops = nubOrdOn fun
        [ Oper GlobalUse g (RVar d) None
        | (i, Oper _ d _ _) <- reverse ios
        , Just g <- [gdefs M.!? i]
        , g `elem` guses'
        ]
```

Answer (score 4):

> And there is no reason to place its sub-function in module scope

Think about it the other way around. Is there any reason to put the sub-function in the local scope? Then do it. This could be because

1. it needs to access locally bound variables. In this case it *must* be local, or else you need extra parameters.
2. it does something very obvious and only relevant to the specific use case. This could be one-line definitions of some operation that you don't care thinking a properly descriptive name, or it could be a `go` helper that does basically the whole work of the enclosing function.

If neither of these apply, and you *can* give the local function a descriptive name (as you've already done) then put it in module scope. Add a type signature, which makes it clearer yet. Don't export it from the module.

Putting the function in module scope also removes the need to rename variables like you did with `gdefs'`. That's one of the more common causes for bugs in Haskell code.

Comment: >> Putting the function in module scope also removes the need to rename variables like you did with gdefs'. That's one of the more common causes for bugs in Haskell code.

-- =====================
Thank you for additionaly notice this issue.
It have coused bugs already.