# what is the correct Haskell syntax for this 'where' clause?

Tags: haskell, where-clause

what is the appropriate correction for this syntax? Is it an issue white space? I copied the whitespace used in examples in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where), also tried other variations gleaned from [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29575426/907924).

I'm sure there's better ways to write this, but I'm not really any good at point free code yet. I'm *novice* level and trying to master the very elementary syntax things that continue to trip me up by doing lots of codewars exercises.

```
import Data.List (findIndices)

basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x y z = (operations  !! (op x)) y z
    where op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" :: Char -> Int
    operations = [(+), (-), (*), (div)]  :: [(Int -> Int -> Int)]
```

when I write like this as one function making reference to two other functions it works.

```
import Data.List (findIndices)

operations :: [(Int -> Int -> Int)]
operations = [(+), (-), (*), (div)]

op :: Char -> Int
op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" 

basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x y z = (operations  !! (op x)) y z
```

the code with the where clause returns these errors:

```
codewars.hs:103:34: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Char -> Int’
    • Probable cause: ‘op’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘(op x)’
      In the expression: (operations !! (op x)) y z
      In an equation for ‘basicOp’:
          basicOp x y z
            = (operations !! (op x)) y z
            where
                op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" :: Char -> Int
                operations = [(+), ....] :: [(Int -> Int -> Int)]
    |
103 | basicOp x y z = (operations  !! (op x)) y z
    |                                  ^^^^

codewars.hs:104:18: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char -> Int’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • Possible cause: ‘($)’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" :: Char -> Int
      In an equation for ‘op’:
          op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" :: Char -> Int
      In an equation for ‘basicOp’:
          basicOp x y z
            = (operations !! (op x)) y z
            where
                op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" :: Char -> Int
                operations = [(+), ....] :: [(Int -> Int -> Int)]
    |
104 |     where op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" :: Char -> Int
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

my original attempt is probably easier to read, but this is just an exercise to try and use more Haskell constructs which I'm not familiar with yet.

```
basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp oper x y
    | oper == '+'  = (+)   x y 
    | oper == '-'  = (-)   x y
    | oper == '*'  = (*)   x y
    | oper == '/'  = (div) x y
```

From the comments, by @DanielWagner, this is improved to:

```
basicOp c = case c of
    '+' -> (+)
    '-' -> (-)
    '*' -> (*)
    '/' -> div
```

Comment: I think I'd be *very* tempted to write `basicOp c = case c of '+' -> (+); '-' -> (-); '*' -> (*); '/' -> div`. It's like a third the length and its meaning is immediately visually clear.

Comment: yes agreed, @DanielWagner my first attempt used pattern matching, but I'm trying to learn how to be more resourceful with primitive Haskell constructs. I'll put my first attempt into Q for completeness.

Comment: use explicit separators `... where { x = ... ; y z = ... }` and forget about whitespace / indentation problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the body of the `op x` expression is an `Int`, not a `Char -> Int`. You should also position `operations` at the same column as `op`, so:

```
basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x y z = (operations  !! (op x)) y z
    where op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" :: Int
          operations = [(+), (-), (*), (div)]  :: [(Int -> Int -> Int)]
```

But the types are not necessary, you can simplify this to:

```
basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x = (operations  !! op x)
    where op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/"
          operations = [(+), (-), (*), (div)]
```

and work with [**`lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup):

```
basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x | Just y <- lookup x operations = y
          | otherwise = …
    where operations = [('+', (+)), ('-', (-)), ('*', (*)), ('/', div)]
```

where `…` is an expression that is then evaluated if the key is not found

Comment: thx, isn't `op` a function that takes some Char and returns an Int? That type declaration seemed to work when it was a stand alone function.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil: yes, `op` has type `Char -> Int`, but the *body* of the function has type `Int`, since `x` is in the head of `op` and the expression of `head (findIndices (== x) "+-*/")` is thus an `Int`.

Comment: thanks for `lookup` — I wanted to use findIndex, but it returns a Maybe_Int and I didn't know how to extract the Int value and deal with the possible nothing being returned inside this function. didn't think to use guards. I barely get Functors yet… was on my to do list :-)

Comment: lookup is nice, I was wondering about some kind of use of tuples for more coherence and less lines of code. thanks again I appreciate the help.

Comment: Didn't know you can put guards in after already stating one argument! i.e. after the `x` arg the `| Just y…`

Answer (score 3):

Note that you *can* provide a type for the function itself, either on a separate line

```
basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x y z = (operations  !! (op x)) y z
    where
        op :: Char -> Int
        op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/"
        operations = [(+), (-), (*), (div)]  :: [(Int -> Int -> Int)]
```

or by providing an explicit lambda expression as the value for `op`.

```
basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x y z = (operations  !! (op x)) y z
    where op = (\x -> head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/") :: Char -> Int
          operations = [(+), (-), (*), (div)]  :: [(Int -> Int -> Int)]
```

Comment: Copied the OP's original and forgot to adjust, thanks.

Comment: The separate line approach turns out to be the more important one, for technical reasons. (`MonomorphismRestriction` and `MonoLocalBinds`, at least, force its use for certain purposes.) So it's probably better to get used to doing it that way except within an expression.

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't get into that, mainly because I can never remember what, exactly, the implications are :) (Also, I always think of `op x = ...` as being syntactic sugar for `op = \x -> ...`, but if I recall, that's backwards.)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, removing the type declarations for `op` and `operations` works.

I thought it was ok (helpful even) to put type declarations "inline" sometimes.

```
basicOp :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Int
basicOp x y z = (operations  !! (op x)) y z
    where 
        op x = head $ findIndices (== x) "+-*/" 
        operations = [(+), (-), (*), (div)]
```